# Safest method to clean up my .bash_profile on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, path, anaconda, conda

I'm new to the Mac environment and installed the Anaconda GUI by accident. I wished to remove it completely and install Miniconda instead. I think I was successful, except the only remnant I can find of Anaconda is in my `.bash_profile`. It looks something like:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/connor/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/connor/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/connor/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/connor/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Is `.bash_profile` something included with my system by default? How should I revert all of the changes Anaconda made to my file or would I be safe to just delete it entirely?

Note: I do not have Miniconda installed yet and am waiting to completely remove all traces of Anaconda first.

**Edit:**
Additionally, I have found more artifacts in `.xonshrc` and `.zshrc`. They show, respectively:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
import sys as _sys
from types import ModuleType as _ModuleType
_mod = _ModuleType("xontrib.conda",
                   "Autogenerated from $(/Users/connor/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.xonsh hook)")
__xonsh__.execer.exec($("/Users/connor/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda" "shell.xonsh" "hook"),
                      glbs=_mod.__dict__,
                      filename="$(/Users/connor/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.xonsh hook)")
_sys.modules["xontrib.conda"] = _mod
del _sys, _mod, _ModuleType
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

and

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/connor/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/connor/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/connor/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/connor/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The bash profile is a set up script which runs when you open the terminal. In the script you provided, the conda lines sets up the PATH environment variable, where in those lines the base conda environment is added to the start of the path. That way if the os searches for any binary files (e.g. python) it first searches conda and the currently activated environment. Since you deleted all anaconda files and its associated binaries, this bash_profile script should now do nothing.

As Gordon Davisson mentioned, the bash_profile does not exist by default on your mac. If bash_profile doesn't currently exist, then the conda installer will create the bash_profile and add the conda set up lines. Otherwise it simply appends the set up lines to the script. In general, it's safest to only remove the conda specific lines in the bash_profile as other programs may too rely on environment variables set in the bash_profile. However if the bash_profile only contains conda related lines, then you can safely delete the entire file.

Comment: Ahh thank you for your response. Would I be safe to delete ".xonshrc" and ".zshrc" as well in that case?

Comment: A lot of the 'rc' files are similarly also set up scripts for when you initially open the terminal. The zshrc is similar to the bashrc (and bash_profile) scripts and sets up the initial environment (but for zsh, a shell similar to bash), but sometimes programs may need certain environment variables and will overwrite your zshrc file. However it's highly likely that if you opened your zshrc file there wouldn't be much in there except maybe conda activation, so I think it'd be safe to delete that too. Not sure what .xonshrc is though.

Comment: I double checked all the files that I found Anaconda edited and there were barren, save for what Anaconda included. My system is brand new so I didn't expect to find any other additions. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: “*automatically overwrite*” - no, it appends to the init files, and the installer asks first. I find it unclear whether you recommend deleting the conda-specific lines (good) or deleting the whole profile (bad).

Comment: However I thought that if the profile files don't exist, then the conda installer creates them and adds the conda set up lines of code. I'm aware that other files may depend on the environments set up in the profiles, and if these need to be preserved then you would simply delete all the conda lines, however if only conda lines are present is it not safe to delete the entire bash_profile for it to be created when you next install conda?

Comment: I agree. I mainly want to suggest you state that more clearly in the answer body (e.g., "remove the sections added by Conda; if that's all that is in a file, the file itself can be removed"). Also, note that I cannot change my vote until you edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

None of these files (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, and `~/.xonshrc`) exist by default in macOS, so if the Anaconda setup is the only thing there, it's safe to just delete them. With one slight caveat: it's possible some other file/script will assume they exist and try to `source` (or `.`) them; it might be worth grepping all the dotfiles in your home directory for occurrences of those filenames.

BTW, the default contents of a newly-created macOS user home directory are in `/System/Library/User Template/*` -- there's a `.../Non_localized` subdirectory with most of the contents, and per-language subdirectories (e.g. `.../English.lproj`) with language-specific additions. You can see what's there with:

```
sudo ls -lA '/System/Library/User Template/'{Non_localized,English.lproj}
```